# mac ports - progress option?

Tags: macos, terminal, macports

I am install gedit on my Mac via macports. I ran the following command,

```
sudo port install gedit
```

There are MANY dependencies for gedit, and macports has been downloading/installing them for the last 2 hours. Is there a command line option for it to show progress as it's downloading, building, and installing each individual package?

Comment: You seem to have asked this on the wrong site. I voted to migrate it to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) because no migration path to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) is available, though the latter is probably a better match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you need to edit /opt/local/share/macports/Tcl/port1.0/portfetch.tcl,

change 'curl' to another program for example axel or wget and then redirect to your current TTY,you can also use 'tty' command to get the current TTY